# Installing React-Native/error msg 404 - What must a programer do in this situation?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

I looked up the error code: ERR! 404 | Many reasons... I'm thinking a package issue?

npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'native-react-cli@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\brfor\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-04-21T19_13_55_438Z-debug.log

C:\Users\brfor>npm config set registry https://skimdb.npmjs.com/registry

C:\Users\brfor>npm install -g native-react-cli
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Object Not Found - GET https://skimdb.npmjs.com/registry/native-react-cli - not_found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'native-react-cli@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.   <-----------------------------Should I try this?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\brfor\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-04-21T19_21_52_469Z-debug.log

file:///C:/Users/brfor/AppData/Roaming/npm-cache/_logs/2020-04-21T19_21_52_469Z-debug.log

Comment: What does this mean... "You should bug the author to publish it or use the name yourself!" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've just tried to install `native-react-cli`, a package that doesn't exist. The package is actually called `react-native-cli`, but you shouldn't even be installing it globally anymore, just use `npx`. Please read the [setup guide](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup), it is all in there.

Comment: Its a good idea to generally type instead of copy and pasting when you're learning though. Good job! :)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have since posting this question have installed via npx.

Answer (score 0):

Installing `native-react-cli` gives error because it doesn't exist. You can try the command `sudo npm install -g create-react-app` for running react in your pc.